# Getting Error 405 for post request to REST api using Java Jersey api

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-client

I wrote a method using Jersey API to make a post request to an api. The api requires the data being posted be in JSON format and has requires a Basic Authorization header however when I run the code below and pass the object it results in the following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 405
at com.shumbamoney.yomoney.SendRequest.send(SendRequest.java:40)
```

.The java code is below.

```
 public String send(TransactionRequestObject tRObject){

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Gson gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder().create();
    String jsonRObject = gsonBuilder.toJson(tRObject);


    ApiCredentials credentials = new ApiCredentials();
    postUrl = credentials.getURL();
    AgentCode = credentials.getAgentCode();
    Password = credentials.getPassword();
    System.out.println(jsonRObject);

   // jersey code
    try{
        Client client = Client.create();
        WebResource webResource = client.resource(postUrl);
        ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1").header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic "+
                AgentCode+":"+Password).post(ClientResponse.class, jsonRObject);
        if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + response.getStatus());
        }

        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println(output);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "success";
}
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Error 405 (method not allowed) is given when the server does not allow you to access a certain resource with a certain methiod. in Your case it looks that the server doesn't allow You to access  that page with POST method.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The api documentation specifies that it should be a post request. I did try to use a get request but it produced the following result    {
    "Message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."
}

Comment: Is there a response body? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code did all the things it should: send the request and get the response from the API, so the error doesn't come from your code, it's from the server that you are requesting to.
try using postman to POST to that url, if you still get the 405 error, than you can make sure that the problem is not from ur code.

Comment: Thank you let me attempt to do that. I will give feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your contributions I really appreciate them. It turns out the issue was on the server that I was requesting to.